# Animate grid row height change in WP

Tags: windows-phone-8, grid, storyboard, animated

I want to animate the grid row height change, but how to do that with dynamic "star" height values?

I have the following grid:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="baseGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="grid0" Grid.Row="0" Tap="grid0_Tap">
        // Content
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="grid1" Grid.Row="1" Tap="grid1_Tap">
        // Content
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="grid2" Grid.Row="2">
        // Content
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In code behind I have logic that if user clicks grid0, grid2 gets hidden. Again if user click grid1, grid2 gets its size back.

```cs
private void grid0_Tap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(0);
}

private void grid1_Tap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star);
}
```

This works well right now, but how to animate this? I think Storyboard needs its from/to value and as Im using dynamic sizes I can not use Storyboard?

Comment: The question isn't clear. "grid3 gets hidden" but no "grid3" is defined in your XAML.

Comment: Sorry, mixed up the grid names. Fixed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDITED to address the Windows Phone 8 animation storyboard question)

An animation class for `GridLength` doesn't exist in any XAML library.

But you can get close, or you can turn to third-party controls which do what you want.

And, for *this* use case, code-behind is pretty much required, instead of defining a XAML resource, since you're discovering the ActualHeight of the element at run-time:

```
private double storedHeight = 0.0;
    private void grid0_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        //ListBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
        if (storedHeight == 0.0) return;
        var d = new DoubleAnimation();
        d.From = 0.0;
        d.To = storedHeight;
        d.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
        storedHeight = 0.0;
        var s = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard.SetTarget(d, grid2);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(d, new PropertyPath("Height"));
        s.Children.Add(d);
        s.Begin();

    }

    private void grid1_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        //ListBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        if (storedHeight > 0.0) return;
        storedHeight = ListBox1.ActualHeight;
        var d = new DoubleAnimation();
        d.From = storedHeight;
        d.To = 0.0;
        d.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);

        var s = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard.SetTarget(d, grid2);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(d, new PropertyPath("Height"));
        s.Children.Add(d);
        s.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: The problem here is that I want to use dynamic scaling, to get the application working in all phones resolutions. Basically in first element (grid0) there is map controller, second (grid1) contains text box and the last one (grid2) has longListSelector. To get the above example workin I need to specify exact height dimensions for Border elemtns. But how to handle this with different screen resolutions?

Comment: Thanks Rob, but I think BeginAnimation is not supported in Windows Phone? At least when I try to use it with longListSelector or with map, I get error ...does not contain a definition for 'BeginAnimation' .

Comment: You're right; that's missing in WP8 SDK. But you had a WPF tag on your post, so I thought it would be a satisfactory answer. Hopefully this one will work for you. See edits.

Comment: Hmmm, with this example I can nicely hide the ListBox but I think I need to set the grid row definition height. As now the ListBox gets hidden, the grid row definitions stays the same and the map control in top does not expand, even the ListBox is hidden.

Comment: An Animation class for `GridLength` doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, managed to make this workin changing my baseGrid little, setting row height to auto etc. But animating the map control height change is not so smooth. Map control updates map content only after the animation stops, at least in my Lumia 820. In emulator it is little bit better...

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a sensible thing to want to do, and a grid animation like this is going to look awful because it's not on the compositor, but:

```
private void grid0_Tap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(0);
}

private void grid1_Tap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double fromHeight = this.LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions[2].ActualHeight;

    this.LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star);
    this.LayoutRoot.Measure(new Size(this.Width, this.Height));

    double toHeight = this.LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions[2].DesiredSize.Height;

    MyStoryboard.From = fromHeight;
    MyStoryboard.To = toHeight;
    MyStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Any other ideas how to approach similar functionality? I can use any other control than grid too.